# Using templates to define static arrays in a class

Tags: c++, templates

I thought this would be really easy, but I have yet to get this working. I want to use templates to define the size of a static unsigned char array data member of a class. I am using templates on two of my functions to define the data types being used, and that works fine. I was thinking something like this:

```
template<unsigned S>
class Buff
{
private:
    static unsigned char buffer[S];
    int offset;
public:
    pAllocBuff(){offset=0;};
    template <typename T>
    T* New(T, int);
    template <typename T>
    T* New(T);

};
```

The idea is that New(T, int) allocates memory from buffer for a data type array.

ie: `char* i = myBuff.New<char>('\0',15); //allocate 15 byte array to i from buffer and initialized to '\0'`

or New(T) allocates memory from the buffer for a single data type

ie: `string* j = myBuff.New<string>("Hello Stack Overflow!"); //allocate memory to string object j from buffer and initialize`

If i replace 'S' with BUFFSIZE and #define BUFFSIZE 1024*1024 (or whatever), everything works great. But i want to make it so that the size of the buffer can be defined for different instances of Buff. So, like:

`Buff<1024*1024> myBuff;`

When I do this, all the member functions in my class are flagged as missing template arguments, even though S has nothing to do with them.

EDIT: I got this working with the suggestion below. I guess im confused why

'template'

needs to be above every function in the class, even though S is not used in that function. Is this just required because it is over the class?
Thanks for your knowledge!

Comment: You need to show the actual errors, and the actual code that uses this. In the version that has the problem

Comment: is  `pAllocBuff()` a typo? it should be `Buff()`

Comment: yes, its a typo, sorry guys. Its just Buff().

Comment: `Is this just required because it is over the class`? **Yes**, it is required because you are defining members of a _class template_, and the non-template version of the class isn't even declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways, this works out fine for me: **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/3L72Lq$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3L72Lq%240)**

```
template<unsigned S>
class Buff
{
private:
    static unsigned char buffer[S];
    int offset;
public:
    Buff() : offset() {}
    template <typename T> T* New(T, int);
    template <typename T> T* New(T);
};   

template<unsigned S>
/*static*/
    unsigned char Buff<S>::buffer[S] = {0};

template<unsigned S>
    template <typename T> T* Buff<S>::New(T, int)
{
    return nullptr; // TODO
}

template<unsigned S>
    template <typename T> T* Buff<S>::New(T)
{
    return nullptr; // TODO
}

int main()
{
    Buff<(1u<<12)> one;
    Buff<(1u<<14)> two;
}
```

I'm sure it's a minor syntax mishap with the member function templates inside the class template, defined out-of-class (which you didn't show).

Comment: This works! I tried something like that but it didnt work before. I must have put something in the wrong spot or something. can you explain why template<unsigned S> is needed over every member function, even though S is not used? Also, by declaring the buffer as static, does this mean that other instances of the class withh share the same buffer?? Thanks again.

Comment: @radensb why don't you compare the two, so that you see what the problem was and _learn_ from the experience? Cheers

Comment: I have changed and modified this so many times, I have nothing to compare to. I just remember trying something like this before, but i'll bet I never put the template<unsigned S> code above every member function, which is probably why VS was flagging it as an error.

Comment: @radensb May I heartily suggest (a) taking small steps (b) using revision control (like Mercurial on Windows, which has awesome shell integration using TortoiseHg)